# Identify night blooming cactus

Tags: identification, cactus

The following plant lives in a pot, outside at a veranda, in southern Greece.

It blooms every year during the night, usually early in the summer. The flowers are strongly fragrant and stay open only for the night. After that, they very slowly wither away.

The spiky 'fruit' at the base of the flower stalk readily attracts a lot of aphids in the earlier stages of development.

The plant typically encounters tempratures no less than 8C during the winter months, but it have witnessed (not covered in) light snow two times with no ill effects whatsoever.

Can you identify it?

[An open flower[image: open flower]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLrWF.jpg)
[Developing flowers[image: overview]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkU2h.jpg)
[Lower part of the plant[image: lower stem]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MMP6.jpg)
[Young fruit[image: fruit closeup]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGRgA.jpg)
[Dissection of a young fruit[image: young fruit dissection]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAsXR.jpg)
[Dissected young fruit close-up[image: young fruit dissection closeup]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4d7f.jpg)
[Dissection of an old fruit[image: old fruit dissection closeup]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ETx.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of the flowers and stems, it appears to be something in the [Selenicereus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenicereus) genus (a moonlight cactus), similar to dragonfruit.

If I'm wrong, it must be another cactus in the [Hylocereeae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylocereeae) tribe.

I have no idea which species it is. The spines on the fruit are rather unique, and I haven't found anything that matches it. I have found plants with spines on the fruit, but they look a lot different.

Comment: I think you're right. It seems like [Selenicereus hamatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenicereus_hamatus). More pictures can be found [here](https://inaturalist.nz/taxa/274246-Selenicereus-hamatus/browse_photos) and of course google.

Answer (score 1):

Well well, you got a night queen...

Oops!! Sorry..**Queen of the Night** aka **Dutchman's pipe cactus** aka **princess of the night**.

Or, ***Epiphyllum oxypetalum***.

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyllum_oxypetalum),

> Though it is sometimes referred to as a night-blooming cereus, it is not closely related to any of the species in the tribe Cereeae, such as Selenicereus, that are more commonly known as night-blooming cereus. All Cereus species bloom at night and are terrestrial plants; Epiphyllum species are usually epiphytic.

Comment: Flower looks quite close, but the rest of the plant (as seen on the wiki link) looks **very** different...

Comment: However, it does seem to be likely the right ID for a flat-leafed cactus that has never budded or flowered in all the years we've cared for it that has just budded up, so for that, a +1.